# Plot 2 variables with different length to display proportion, not absolute numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare the responses to the same question asked in two different surveys. The results of the two surveys are in two dataframes, DF1 and DF2, and the responses to the question are in variable V1:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option1", "Option1", "Option2", NA)),
                  ID1 = factor(c("Resp1", "Resp1", "Resp3", "Resp4", "Resp5")))
DF2 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option1", "Option1", "Option2", "Option2", NA, "Option1")),
                  ID2 = factor(c("PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", "PersonD", "PersonE", "PersonF", "PersonG")))
```

Because the number of responses to both surveys was different, when I plot the responses from the two surveys one next to the other, the resulting barplot can be quite confusing and difficult to interpret:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- DF1 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF1", n=n())
DF2 <- DF2 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF2", n=n())
DF <- rbind(DF1, DF2) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(V1))
ggplot(DF, aes(x=V1, y=n, fill=DF)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

I'd like to change the code so that the bars contain the proportion of each survey's respondents that selected each option, rather than their number. How can it be done?

Comment: Depends on how one wants to present the data, I guess. It's an easy change to make if needed: `ggplot(DF, aes(x=DF, y=n/total, fill=V1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option1", "Option1", "Option2", NA)),
                                ID1 = factor(c("Resp1", "Resp1", "Resp3", "Resp4", "Resp5")))

DF2 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option1", "Option1", "Option1", "Option2", "Option2", NA, "Option1")),
                                    ID2 = factor(c("PersonA", "PersonB", "PersonC", "PersonD", "PersonE", "PersonF", "PersonG")))

DF1 <- DF1 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF1", n=n()) %>% mutate(total = sum(n))

DF2 <- DF2 %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(DF="DF2", n=n()) %>% mutate(total = sum(n))

DF <- rbind(DF1, DF2) %>% 
        filter(!is.na(V1))


ggplot(DF, aes(x=V1, y=n/total, fill=DF)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```